CodeIgniter 4 does not send attachment
helper('inflector');
    $pdfFileName = underscore(WRITEPATH.'uploads\invoice '.$invoice_number.'.pdf');
    file_put_contents($pdfFileName, $dompdf->output());

    if (file_exists($pdfFileName) && is_readable($pdfFileName)) {

    //  send email
    $email = \Config\Services::email();       

    $email->setFrom('satechs.solutions@gmail.com', 'SaTechs Solutions');
    $email->setTo($data['bill_to']);
    $email->setSubject('Invoice for ' . $invoice_number);
    $email->setMessage('<h3> Dear ' . $data['clientname'] . ',</h4>' . '<br>' . 'Please find the attached invoice that is due on: ' . $data['due_date']. '.');
    $email->attach($pdfFileName); 
    $email->send();

The pdf is generated successfully and is available, the email is sent successfully, only that text message alone is sent.
The attachment is not sent

possible duplicate

If you inspect the source code of the message in your client, does it show any information from the attachment? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure your problem is related to [tag:sendmail] or [tag:send]?

Are you using gmail smtp?
